# Using external log4j.properties file with Grails

Tags: grails, log4j

What's the best way to use an external log4j.properties file within Grails? I'd like to use the traditional log4j.properties format rather than a log4j.groovy style configuration.

I'm also curious if the external configuration will play nicely with the log4j.properties file that's created by `grails war` and put into the war file. If I remove the log4j configuration from Config.groovy will the log4j.properties still be put into the war file?

Comment: I revisited this today and found [this blog post](http://techbeats.deluan.com/how-to-use-an-external-log4jproperties-in-you-0) which offers a way to do this using Spring's Log4jConfigurer bean. If I have a chance to try it out I may post an answer.

Answer (score 6):

In Grails 1 and 2, there's a [logging DSL](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging) that is configured and used in an out-of-the-box webapp, so you'll want to remove the `log4j = { ... }` code from `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`

If you want to use an external configuration file for logging like in a typical Java web application, then update the file `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` with the following.

```
beans = {
    log4jConfigurer(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean) {
        targetClass = "org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"
        targetMethod = "initLogging"
        arguments = ["classpath:log4j.properties"]
    }
}
```

Note that the package name used in your Log4j appender configuration will probably not be what you expect, since it will have a Grails-specific prefix added onto it...

```
WARN grails.app.controllers.org.example.BookController - This is a warn log message from BookController
ERROR grails.app.controllers.org.example.BookController - This is an error log message from BookController
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using 1.0.x series:

- copy War.groovy from $GRAILS_HOME/scripts to your $APP/scripts
- comment out lines 145 and 154 of the copied War.groovy
- put your log4j.properties into $APP/grails-app/conf
- run $ grails war, and it will prompt you to choose which War script to run, then choose your local one (usually #1).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Log4J Plugin](http://www.grails.org/Log4j+XML+Plugin) which states:

"Some old-school Java developers are more comfortable with log4j.xml even though the configuration file is much larger. This plugin provides a way to disable the default Log4j DSL and allow the use of log4j.xml either in the original form, or in Groovy MarkupBuilder style."

I haven't used it myself so can't speak to its usability in the WAR context.. Just WAR up your app, and then try it out.. It should be under the WEB-INF folder somewhere obvious. If that doesn't work, *Mingfai* on the *[grails user list](http://grails.org/Mailing+lists)* can probably help you out.

Comment: +1 This is a reasonable solution, but won't quite work for me, since I'm using Grails 1.0.3 (the plugin only works for 1.1). A helpful answer, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At least in 1.0.x series (not checked in 1.1) forget about Grails support and rely directly on Spring. Just use the log4jConfigLocation parameter in web.xml. More info [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jWebConfigurer.html)